# How to check if all keys of a dictionary present in another dictionary?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

Given two dictionaries, I want to find out whether all the keys are present in the second dictionary.

Example: `d1 = {'a':2, 'b':3, 'c':5} d2 = {'a':2, 'b':2}`

Expected output: `True` or `False`.

I used intersection operation to find the dictionary with common elements, and if the length of the result is equal to the length of d2, then I do the desired computation.

I am looking for an optimized approach because my data is very large.

I have a list of strings (up to 10<sup>4</sup>) and another list containing the words to be searched in the given string. For each string, I am using Counter operation to get a dictionary of words format, and applying a similar approach for query strings too. Now I have to check each testing string against each query input.

Here is my approach:

```
def textQueries(sentences, queries):
    bagsofwords = [ Counter(re.findall(r'\w+', sentence)) for sentence in sentences]
    #print(bagsofwords)
    bagofqueries = [ Counter(re.findall(r'\w+', query)) for query in queries]
    #print(bagofqueries)
    si = [[]for y in range(len(queries))]
    search_count = [0]*len(bagofqueries)


for j in range(0,len(bagofqueries)):
     if search_count[j] < 10:
        boq = bagofqueries[j]
        for i in range(0,len(bagsofwords)):
            t = bagsofwords[i] & boq

            if len(t) == len(boq):
                #Doing operation.
```

Any suggestion would be helpful.

Comment: It isn't clear if you want to find if the keys of one dict are a subset of the keys of the second one, or if you want to check for equality.

Answer (score 3):

```
set(d1) <= set(d2)
```

`set` converts a dictionary to a set of its keys. We can then use `<=` to check for set inclusion.

Comment: This is the most Pythonic of the answers currently. But instead of converting to `set`, I'd use `d1.keys() <= d2.keys()`. I'd guess that it's more efficient, as it doesn't necessarily have to actually create the sets. But it's worth testing.

Comment: @interjay would get the wrong answer with their suggested `d1.keys() <= d2.keys()`. Example: `dict(a=1, b=2).keys() <= dict(b=1).keys()` gives `True`, which is not the right answer.

Comment: I tested your example and it gives `False`. I'm guessing you're running Python 2, but the question is about Python 3.

Comment: Why isn't it this -- set(d1) == set(d2)

Comment: The original question didn't say that he wanted the set of keys to be identical, merely that all of the keys in the first dictionary were also present in the second dictionary. The second dictionary may have keys that are not in the first dictionary and that would be fine (at least according to the question phrasing).

Answer (score 1):

A simple loop over the the `keys()` and checking against the `keys()` within the second `dict`:

```
d1 = {'a':2, 'b':3, 'c':5} 
d2 = {'a':2, 'b':2}

def all_keys(d1,d2):
    for key in d1.keys():
      if key not in d2.keys():
        return False
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`all()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all):

```
def all_keys_available(d1, d2):
    return all(k in d2 for k in d1)
```

**Usage**:

```
>>> d1 = {'a':2, 'b':3, 'c':5}
>>> d2 = {'a':2, 'b':2}
>>> all_keys_available(d1, d2)
False
```

Comment: Thanks, but I tried this, I am looking for a more optimal way.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Counter` from `collections` module. which is faster.

```
from collections import Counter
d1 = {'a':2, 'b':3, 'c': 2} 
d2 = {'a':2, 'b':2}
print(Counter(d1.keys()) == Counter(d2.keys())) // False

d1 = {'a':2, 'b':3} 
d2 = {'a':2, 'b':2}
print(Counter(d1.keys()) == Counter(d2.keys())) // True
```

Comment: keys in a dictionary are unique so `Counter` is unnecessary, `set` would be sufficient.

Comment: Both `Counter` and `set` are unnecessary, as `keys` returns a `set`-like object already.

Answer (score 0):

Matrix Programmer this side,
You can use the keys() method to get the keys and then compare them!

```
a = {'a' : 1, 'b' : 2, 'c' : 1}
b = {'a' : 1, 'b' : 2, 'c' : 1}

print(a.keys()) #By the keys() method we get all the keys of a dict like a in this case
print(b.keys()) #Just to show it...

if a.keys() == b.keys() : #Checks if the two dicts' keys match...
    print(True) #Will print true if the two dicts have the same keys
else :
    print(False)

#I would though prefer to convert them into list before comparing them that way it becomes easy for the
#interpreter to understand the code and it may not give an error at times this method may...
```

Hope this solved your problem bye! Wish u all good!